# Do Kotlin's access modifiers mean the same thing as in Java?

Tags: oop, inheritance, access-modifiers, kotlin

Kotlin has 3 keywords for access: `public`, `private` and `protected`. Do they mean the same thing as in Java, or are there differences? Also, is `internal` the same as `package private`? I keep reading about "modules" in Kotlin, and I'm not sure if that's just another word for "package".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin's access modifiers *do not* always mean the same thing as in Java. For example, Kotlin allows `protected` members in interfaces while Java does not.

Modules are compile-time only entities. They group source files and declare dependencies for them (binary libraries and other modules). A module is a unit of compilation, i.e. all of its files are compiled together (in fact there is file-by-file incremental compilation, but its effect must be the same as re-compiling the whole module).

For example, each Maven `pom` implicitly declares a module, and IDE has modules in the Project View and Project Structure.